# How to Use The (a href="#") in a Button

Tags: javascript, html

Okay so this code is very known:

```
<a href="#" id="link1">LINK</a>
```

I want to have the same effect using an input button, I tried:

```
<input type="button" value="LINK" onclick="#">
```

but obviously it didn't work. Any other way to do so? Thanks :)

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires this? Maybe there is a better solution if you provide more details

Comment: @Gabs00 I am not very sure but whenever I click the link the whole scripts function. Friend said so and it is working as a link. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to accomplish rather than what's wrong with your current solution. @Gabs00 is correct. There is no reason I can imagine to do what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a `href` element to an `input` tag.

I'm guessing you want to do this so you can have a link with the styling of a button? If that's the case you can use CSS to achieve the look and feel of a button that uses an `anchor` tag.

Most CSS frameworks (in particular [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)) have classes that allow you to do this. For example, in Bootstrap:

```
<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Text</a>
```

Will render a link that looks like a button.

The CSS for this (which is available on the [Bootstrap GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/buttons.less)) looks something like this:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}
```

Obviously, being a framework, there's a lot of other styles that go into the mix but that gives you a start if you don't want to use Bootstrap.

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwvarxaj/)

Answer (score 1):

Could try using `location.replace()`

```css
div {
  position:relative;
  top:300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="LINK" onclick="location.replace('#abc')">
<div id="abc">abc</div>
```

Comment: See also `location.assign()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might be interested in a `form` with a `submit` input:

```
<form method="get" action="place_to_go.html">
    <input type="submit" value="LINK" />
</form>
```

The `submit` input renders like a `button`. Once clicked, the user will be taken to `place_to_go.html`.